# Autofac: register open generic types as instances of non-generic abstract parent types?

Tags: c#, generics, inversion-of-control, autofac

I am maintaining legacy code with a dynamic and flexible plugin system, which is implemented as a very shallow class tree where all concrete plugins extend the abstract `Plugin` class. Most of these plugins are concrete classes (such as `LoadSound`, `HighPassFilter`), but some of them have one generic type parameter (like `CreateCopy<T>`).

The initialisation sequence for this system basically loads all assemblies, lists all their types, selects the ones that are descendants of `Plugin`, and then iterates through them and inserts them into a sort of homebrew IoC container.

To improve the maintainability of this system, I want to replace the homebrew IoC container with Autofac, which is used elsewhere in the codebase.

I have managed to register all types in a useful way, like so:

```cs
Autofac.ContainerBuilder builder;

// Find all classes derived from Plugin, and split them
// up based on whether or not they are generic
ILookup<bool, Type> isGeneric = types.Where(IsPlugin)
    .ToLookup(t => t.IsGenericTypeDefinition);

// Register the generic types as themselves
foreach (Type t in isGeneric[true])
    builder.RegisterGeneric(t)
        .AsSelf()
        .SingleInstance();

// Register all the non-generic types as themselves and
// as instances of Plugin
builder.RegisterTypes(isGeneric[false].ToArray())
    .AsSelf()
    .As<Plugin>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

With this, I can successfully resolve any plugin from the container later created from the `builder`. The issue is that the system also expects a `GetAvailablePlugins` method. My first instinct was to implement this as

```cs
public IReadOnlyCollection<PluginMetaData> GetAvailablePlugins()
{
    return Components.Resolve<IEnumerable<Plugin>>()
        .Select(plugin => new PluginMetaData(plugin.GetType()))
        .ToList<PluginMetaData>();
}
```

(I know resolving manually from the IoC container is a bad idea – but fixing that is the next step, and not the issue I have right now.)

However, this – as you may guess already – will only result in a collection of the non-generic plugins, not the generic ones. I tried, naively, to register the generic types with

```cs
builder.RegisterGeneric(t)
    .AsSelf()
    .As<Plugin>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

but Autofac doesn't want any of it:

```
The service 'Vendor.Common.Plugin' is not an open generic type definition.
```

which is, of course, an accurate observation. It isn't. And I don't expect a resolution attempt for `Plugin` to result in a concrete instance of the generic plugin either – I just want a good way to access all types registered as `Plugin`s without having to duplicate that information elsewhere!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It didn't take many minutes after writing the question until I figured out myself how to do it: I changed my registration logic to

```cs
// Find all classes derived from Plugin
IEnumerable<Type> plugins = types.Where(IsPlugin);

// Register all plugins (generic and non-generic) as children of Plugin
builder.RegisterTypes(plugins.ToArray())
    .AsSelf().As<Plugin>().SingleInstance();

// Register generic plugins in a resolvable way
foreach (Type t in modules.Where(t => t.IsGenericTypeDefinition))
    builder.RegisterGeneric(t).AsSelf().SingleInstance();
```

I am not quite sure *how* this works, but it appears that it registers the generic plugins as though they were non-generic components, somehow. These non-generic components cannot be resolved in the system, but they are returned when asking Autofac for all components implementing the `Plugin` service.

Then *in addition to that* I also register the generic plugins as generic components, which lets the system resolve them with concrete type arguments.

---

**Update**: However, I discovered now that listing all plugins with

```cs
Components.Resolve<IEnumerable<Plugin>>()
        .Select(plugin => new PluginMetaData(plugin.GetType()))
        .ToList<PluginMetaData>();
```

is not a viable route – some plugins have dependencies that aren't feasible to instantiate when running tests that verify some properties of this list of plugins. So I settled with a combination of my answer and the one by [D.R.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400869/d-r):

I now fetch the plugin list with

```cs
Components.ComponentRegistry
    .RegistrationsFor(new TypedService(typeof(BaseModule)))
    .Select(reg => new PluginMetaData(reg.Activator.LimitType))
    .ToList<PluginMetaData>();
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach would be to query the `container.ComponentRegistry` and just find all registered plugins that way.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, that would require me to ask for all registrations and then filter out those that aren't plugins, right?